# WM_DPICHANGED, behavior when when App launches

Tags: delphi, vcl, dpi, delphi-10-seattle

Our delphi app is Per Monitor DPI aware.

Our app is scaled when we receive the WM_DPICHANGED message.

We have a customer who uses two 4K Monitors, both set to 200% DPI Scaling.
When he runs our App it does not scale properly. He is running on Windows 10.

We discovered that when our app launches, the WM_DPICHANGED event is not being triggered **on his PC**.

According to the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn312083(v=vs.85).aspx), WM_DPICHANGED will be fired when:

> - The window is moved to a new monitor that has a different DPI.
> - The DPI of the monitor hosting the window changes.

So according to the documentation, if both monitors are using 200% DPI Scale, it seems as though the event should not fire.

However, when we setup a PC with two monitors each setup to 150% scaling, the WM_DPICHANGED **is** fired when our App lauches and therefore scales just fine.

Should the WM_DPICHANGED be fired when our App launches under the described scenario, what is the expected behaviour?

Which reasons can explain the different behaviour between our setup and our customers setup?

Thank you!

Comment: WM_DPICHANGED should not get fired when app launches. You have to handle initial scaling separately. Why you observe different behavior on your PC is hard to say. I have never encountered such situation.

Comment: which Delphi version do you use?

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar App is compiled with XE-10

Comment: There is no such version as XE10. Read the version off the about box.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Delphi 10 Seattle. I had always referred to it as XE-10 until now. :-)

Comment: Just a guess, but as you comment, the clients machines are identical to each other. Are yours? They might be different DPI to each other. The scaling will not change the fact that they have a different DPI to each other. I am guessing you probably create a form on one screen, then move it to the other if it exists?

Comment: Since you are using VCL built in DPI handling this can either be VCL issue (which it certainly has) or you didn't made proper test. You have to test it outside IDE with same exe to be sure your IDE didn't mess up default form DPI scale giving you different end results.

Comment: Bottom line is this question needs proper [mcve]

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar  as you mentioned in your first comment, WM_DPICHANGED should not fire when the app launches. This is also in line with the documentation regarding this event. We now look at the DPI scale when the app launches and if necessary scale our app. In the next couple of days we should hear back from our customer and hopefully the issue will be solved.